# psql how do you select from a composite array

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, psql, composite-types

```
CREATE TYPE complex AS (
start_time timestamp,
amount int,
);
```

Given a variable

```
my_complexes complex[]
```

how do you query it like a table?

```
SELECT amount FROM my_complexes;
```

Gives "relation does not exist".

```
SELECT mc.amount FROM (SELECT my_complexes) mc;
```

Gives "amount does not exist".

In case it is relevant, my_complexes is passed in as a parameter of a function. I want to then select on that array.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
SELECT (your_column_from_table_ my_complexes).amount FROM my_complexes;
```

Full example:

```
CREATE TYPE complex AS (
   start_time timestamp,
   amount int
);

CREATE TABLE my_complexes (
    clm complex
);

INSERT INTO my_complexes VALUES ((LOCALTIMESTAMP, 112));
SELECT (clm).amount FROM my_complexes;
```

Comment: In my situation, there is no table. I am inside a function where an array of my complex type is passed in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what I was missing was UNNEST(my_complexes)

```
SELECT mc.amount FROM UNNEST(my_complexes) mc;
```